# How to restrict generic type to subtype of a class?

Tags: java, generics

I've the following class hierarchy:

```
class ListItem<T> {
}

abstract class ListView<T> {
    abstract void render(final ListItem<T> item);
}
```

Now, I'd like to create a common implementation of `ListView` that accepts an instance of `Consumer`. My attempt is as follows:

```
class CommonListView<T> extends ListView<T> {

    private final Consumer<ListItem<T>> itemConsumer;

    CommonListView(Consumer<ListItem<T>> itemConsumer) {
        this.itemConsumer = itemConsumer;
    }

    @Override
    void render(ListItem<T> item) {
        itemConsumer.accept(item);
    }
}

interface Consumer<E> {

    void accept(E item);
}
```

It pretty much does what I need, however I'd like to restrict `E` in `Consumer` to be a subtype of `ListItem`. Adding `<E extends ListItem<E>>` unfortunately failed.

Comment: Would it not be <E extends ListItem<?>>

Comment: "Adding <E extends ListItem<E>> unfortunately failed." How so?

Comment: `<T, E extends ListItem<T>>` perhaps?

Comment: `interface Consumer<T>{ void accept(ListItem<T>); }`

Comment: @Sam, that's correct :) Feel free to add an answer to accept!

Comment: @AndyTurner, have you tried your suggestions or you are just guessing? I've provided compilable code sample the let the interested try it out. None of your solutions work.

Comment: "None of your solutions work." Depends how you apply them. I can make them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<E extends ListItem<E>>` is along the correct lines but not quite correct and appears to actually be cyclical.

If you don't care what the ListItem is of, you could do:

```
  <E extends ListItem<?>>
```

However, the more correct version would be as Andy has said to add an extra type parameter, like so:

```
class ListItem<T> {
}

abstract class ListView<T> {
  abstract void render(final ListItem<T> item);
}

class CommonListView<T> extends ListView<T> {

  private final Consumer<T, ListItem<T>> itemConsumer;

  CommonListView(Consumer<T, ListItem<T>> itemConsumer) {
    this.itemConsumer = itemConsumer;
  }

  @Override
  void render(ListItem<T> item) {
    itemConsumer.accept(item);
  }
}

interface Consumer<T, E extends ListItem<T>> {
  void accept(E item);
}
```

However, I think you are saying in your response to Andy that this doesn't work?  Could you clarify how it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) The wildcard `<?>` works well, since I don't care about the actual type unless it's wrapped in `ListItem`. However, I need to guarantee that `T` in `Consumer` and `T` in `CommonListView` are actually of the same type. Can it be done without having two generic types in `Consumer`? I mean both `T` and `E`?

Comment: Ok :) Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

Change the generics on `Consumer` to:

```
interface Consumer<T, E extends ListItem<T>> {
  void accept(E item);
}
```

then add the extra type variable when you declare a variable of this type, for example:

```
static class CommonListView<T> extends ListView<T> {

  private final Consumer<T, ListItem<T>> itemConsumer;

  CommonListView(Consumer<T, ListItem<T>> itemConsumer) {
    this.itemConsumer = itemConsumer;
  }

  @Override
  void render(ListItem<T> item) {
    itemConsumer.accept(item);
  }
}
```